# Unity 5.3 How to load current level?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

before Unity 5.3, I could do

```
Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
```

But now it's something weird with SceneManager. I've read documentation but nothing. How do I get the current scene and load it (Unity 5.3f4)?

Thanks!

Comment: or `SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);`

Answer (score 23):

Use the new [SceneManager](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html) and make sure you include the namespace `UnityEngine.SceneManagement`

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Example
{
    public void ReloadCurrentScene()
    {
        // get the current scene name 
        string sceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;

        // load the same scene
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName,LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way for loading current scene with `SceneMamager` is Something Like this :

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
```

be sure that you have include `SceneManager` in your script.

Answer (score -1):

```
using UnityEngine;    
using UnityEngine.UI;   
using System;   
using System.Collections;  
**using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;**

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour{

public void OnRoomJoin(BaseEvent e)
    {   

        // Remove SFS2X listners and re-enable interface before moving to the main game scene
        //Reset();

        // Goto the main game scene
        **SceneManager.LoadScene(1);**
//     **SceneManager.LoadScene("main");**  
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -3):

it's my C# example:) i had the same problem and now i have figured out with it, you must keep in mind that your scene must be included to the build settings of your project;)
hope this will help others with new canges in it)
Cheers:)
P.S. Add this script to your button in inspector and choose you r script and name of this function:)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class start_new_game : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
public void Update () {

}
public void OnMouseDown()
{
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
 }

}
```

Comment: this is going to be buggy, if you load through scene manager all previously loaded objects will remain