# This content is stale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Application.LoadLevel("GamePlay");

//I'm a beginner and I'm stuck because the system tells me to use this code instead of the Application.

// "SceneManager.LoadScene"

Comment: Are you asking this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170650/unity-5-3-how-to-load-current-level

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're trying to load in a scene titled "GamePlay"? If so, you would do so like this

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadLevel : MonoBehaviour {

  public string levelName;

  public void LoadMyLevel()
   {
      SceneManager.LoadScene(levelName);
   }

}
```

If you are using a UI Button to change levels (which I highly recommend doing) then all you need to do is attach this script to your button object, drag it into the 'OnClick()' function box and expand the drop down menu and find the script name and function you want to call. (In this case, it is LoadLevel, and then LoadMyLevel). Then enter the level name, i.e. GamePlay, into the open variable box. [Image of the Button fields Im talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Jp3.png)